# Javascript array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, instantiation

I want to create/instantiate an array **`objectArray`** with several objects, whereby the objects shall contain x and y (empty at the beginning).

The length (amount of objects) of `objectArray` needs to be the same as the length of i.e. `arrayLong`. **How I have to implement that?**

Finally, it should look like that (**etc.** corresponding to the length of `arrayLong`):

```
var objectArray = [ { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 } etc. ];
```

Comment: Create an empty array and add initialized objects in a loop.

Comment: Can you share your attempt(s) to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
var objectArray = [];               // Declare the array variable
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLong; i++){ // Do something `arrayLong` times
    objectArray.push({x: 0, y:0});  // Add a object to the array.
}
```

This assumes `arrayLong` is a numeric value, of course.

Another way you could do it, is this:

```
var objectArray = Array.apply(null, Array(arrayLong))
                       .map(function(){return {x: 0, y:0}});
```

Comment: Whoops, that should've been `arrayLong`, not `5` :P Thanks, though!